# RHEL 7 does not boot well, but still accessible

Tags: networking, rhel, boot

My RHEL 7 stops here:

[image]

Never proceeds from here. Interestingly, I can still access this machine via SSH from another machine. I can even send a reboot signal. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that the Linux Standard Base networking component of your machine is failing. Since you can ssh to it, ensure that your interfaces in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` are set with `ONBOOT=yes`.

If this doesn't work out, you'd probably need to reinstall your machine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's starting Gnome Display Manager (gdm), but X isn't starting.  Check the logs in /var/log/gdm/.  There will probably be several :0.log, ;1.log ... :6.log files, each of which will say why X didn't start.